# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found on all modules in anaconda environment

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

all imports seems to work fine in Python console but none of them seem to be recognized in the actual script. Also added the DLL folder to Path. Yet it doesn not work.

PyCharm 2019.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-191.6183.50, built on March 19, 2019
JRE: 11.0.2+9-b159.30 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Can you check that you have the same interpreter set for the console and for the project itself? Also, you can try to Invalidate the caches and restart Pycharm (in the `File` menu)

Comment: @Eskapp yes the interpreters for both are the same. Tried invalidating the cache as well. No use.

Comment: Where is Anaconda installed? There's a known PyCharm issue with non-home folder installations https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35141

Comment: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\"

Comment: @PavelKarateev AppData\Local\Continuum is the default anaconda location for Windows platform. I have the same in all of my other PCs and it works.

Comment: `AppData` will fail as well, see my comment https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35141#focus=streamItem-27-3391074.0-0

Answer (score 0):

*Making @PavelKarateev's comment an answer, for other people encountering this error:*

This is an [unfortunate and known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35141) in PyCharm 2019.1. Should be fixed in PyCharm <strike>2019.1.2</strike> 2019.1.3.